# Splash Screen Problem on exiting from application when press exit button kindly help me plz

Tags: java, android, android-activity, splash-screen

**Hello Friends**
actually, I am a beginner app developer
and I am facing this problem this problem hasn't any solution on youtube
Actually when creating a splash screen for my app and making another activity
first, the splash screen launched then the second activity(main page launched)
but when I press the back button my app comes from the main page to the Splash screen
have there any solution that when I press back I exit from the app and do not comes to the splash screen

**Here is Splash screen Code**

```
package com.example.a009hassan;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        Thread threadname = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(800);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    Intent intentname = new Intent(MainActivity.this , MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(intentname);
                }
            }
        };threadname.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your thread, try this :

```
         Thread threadname = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(800);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    Intent intentname = new Intent(MainActivity.this , MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(intentname);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };threadname.start();
```

Comment: Thank you brother my problem has been solved by your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
Intent intentname = new Intent(MainActivity.this , MainActivity2.class);
intentname.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intentname);
finish()
```

Comment: Thank you brother for your help my problem has been solved by your solution

Comment: @maliik_hassan_009 Thank you, Happy to help you.  if you solve your problem please select my answer as correct.